# Swing : animation still stutter when I use Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();

Tags: java, swing, animation, synchronization

I'm trying to draw Image every 100ms time by using Thread.sleep(). But I heard that when using Thread.sleep() with swing, It moves like stutter. so I add code Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync(), but it still looks like stuttering.

Correctly speaking, it looks like delay like 2~300ms and draw at once with short time.

I mean when I want to move Image, I wish to look like

draw - sleep - draw - sleep - ...

but it looks like

draw - sleep - sleep - sleep - draw - draw - draw - sleep - ...

I'm sorry that poor of my explanation, I wish you can understand this.

And here is my code.

```
public abstract class EngineViewer implements Runnable
{
     private int _frameInterval = 100;
     private CameraInterface _camera;

     private Canvas _canvas;

     public EngineViewer(int displayWidth, int displayHeight, int resolutionWidth, int resolutionHeight)
     {
         Thread thread = new Thread(this);
         thread.start();
     }

     private void Sleep()
     {
         try { Thread.sleep(_frameInterval); }
         catch(Exception e) { }
     }


     @Override
     public void run()
     {
         while(true)
         {
             Clear();

             _camera.Draw(_canvas);

             Draw();

             Sleep();
         }
     }

     protected abstract void Draw();
}
```

Register camera to EngineViewer, EngineViewer call Camera.Draw() every time.
Camera draw Image to buffer which is get from SwingViewer._buffer.

And draw _buffer to _panel at Draw Method, after that call Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync().

```
public class SwingViewer extends EngineViewer
 {       
     private JFrame _frame;

     private SWPanel _panel;

     private BufferedImage _buffer;
     private Graphics2D _graphic;

     public SwingViewer(String name, int displayWidth, int displayHeight, int resolutionWidth, int resolutionHeight)
     {
         super(displayWidth, displayHeight, resolutionWidth, resolutionHeight);

         _frame = new JFrame(name);
         _frame.setSize(displayWidth, displayHeight);
         _frame.setVisible(true);
         _frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

         _panel = new SWPanel();
         _frame.add(_panel);
     }

     @Override
     public void Draw()
     {
         if(_panel != null)
             _panel.Draw();

         Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
     }

     private class SWPanel extends JPanel
     {
         private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

         private void Draw()
         {
             repaint();
         }

         @Override
         public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
         {
             super.paintComponent(g);

             g.drawImage(_buffer, 0, 0, EngineViewer.DisplayWidth(), EngineViewer.DisplayHeight(), null);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: There is no need for a while loop and a Thread.sleep(). Instead use a Swing Timer to schedule the animation. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information. Also, method names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment:  This is not how you should be using `Canvas` or `JPanel` to perform animation - Swing is double buffered anyway, so your wasting a lot of time for no reasonable results.  Either you want to use the Swing (passive) painting system or you want to make use a `BufferStrategy` and take complete (active) control over the painting system ... don't try and do both

Comment: @camickr
is there any other way to use Thread.sleep() at all?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm sorry that what does it mean. I think you are saying that choose swing paint system or bufferstrategy, but I can't understand what does it mean exactly. Can you explain about it more detail with some example?

Comment: @신승빈 [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html); [Passive vs Active Rendering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/rendering.html); [Double Buffering and Page Flipping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html)

Comment: @신승빈 *"is there any other way to use Thread.sleep() at all?"* not with your current approach - You should never use `Thread.sleep` when working with Swing, is single thread and not thread safe

Comment: @MadProgrammer ah, Ok. I'll get some more study with your link. Thanks a lot!